# Writing the eigenvectors, obtained using SLEPc, to a file in C

Tags: python, c, mpi, petsc

I have recently started using `SLEPc` for diagonalizing large sparse matrices, taking advantage of `MPI`. Everything works fine, except at the end when I want to write the eigenvectors to a file. I do this:

```
PetscViewerASCIIOpen(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, "./data/eigvecs.txt", &viewer);
PetscViewerPushFormat(viewer, PETSC_VIEWER_ASCII_PYTHON);
EPSVectorsView(eps, viewer);
```

I run my code with `mpiexec -n 3 ./app`. The generated file `eigvecs.txt` looks like this:

```
Vec Object: Xr0_EPS_0x84000004_0 3 MPI processes
 type: mpi
Process [0]
-0.909229
0.415619
Process [1]
-0.00206267
0.00410161
Process [2]
0.0145993
0.01813
Vec Object: Xi0_EPS_0x84000004_0 3 MPI processes
 type: mpi
Process [0]
0.
0.
Process [1]
0.
0.
Process [2]
0.
0.
```

So the components of each eigenvector are printed in parallel and different eigenvectors are separated by a string of 0s, also printed in parallel.

My question: Is there no better way to do this? Because later I would want to read this file in `python` or `julia` and do some computations. If not, what's the best way to read this file in `python` or `julia`?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I figured it's better to use `regex` to extract the floating-point values from the file and store it as a matrix, rather than banging my head over finding another way to write the eigenvectors. So for me, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dumping to ascii and parsing that on input, use `PETSCVIEWERHDF5` to dump an hdf5 file, and use the hdf5 module of python to read the file. That will be faster, and not incur conversion losses.

Comment: Hi, I don't know about the `HDF5` format. As I checked, `PETSc` by default doesn't have `HDF5`, and it needs to be configured with the installed package. On our supercomputer, we have `hdf5_parallel/1.10.7` which I think is pretty old. So will it be ok to work with that? Because when I load this module the `mpi` compiler defaults to an older version!

Comment: You need to install petsc with hdf5 support. Ask your supercomputer administrator, or do it yourself. It's not hard.

Comment: Every programming language has a way of opening a file in binary mode. You need to specify that explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I realized that the problem was with `endianness`. Also, I tried the `HDF5` formatting, and it's great! But the only problem is that the file size is much larger than the binary one! Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hdf5 is a binary format so it should be roughly the same size, with a little overhead added. I'm not sure why it would be "much" larger.